# How to Requeue jobs to Resque?

Tags: resque, resque-retry

I am new to Resque and I have been using it in production for the past 2 months, I now have a problem where I want my jobs to be re-queued in the queue if there is an exception. My jobs make about 50 external HTTP calls and some of the calls fail due to latency and sometimes the service is down. I am exploring https://github.com/lantins/resque-retry but I am trying to understand if resque-retry retries the job or re-queues it, I don't want the failed job to get a precedence over the other jobs in this queue, I want it to be added to the queue again. Also, all my HTTP calls have a rescue block, while using resque-retry do I have to make some changes to this class(which is called from Resque perform) so that it gets retried/re-queued.

Comment: I dont think the failed job get any higher precedence over the other job since in resque term it only a message in the queue the only precedence it can get is perhaps if the queues from from which the failed job message was consumed is of higher precedence over the other queue but if the same queue has some message in it and failed job message arrive then it will function as normal queue fashion i.e FIFO order

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the failed job get any higher precedence over the other jobs in same queues

since in resque term it only a message in the queues the only precedence

it can get is perhaps if the queues from from which the failed job message was consumed

is of higher precedence over the other queues but if the same queue has some message in it

and failed job message arrive then it will function just  as normal queue fashion i.e **FIFO**

order